# search results filter effects - flex

Tags: apache-flex, search, animation, filtering, effects

I've created a search with a couple of comboboxes that allow users to filter their search results.

The results are currently using a TileList & itemRenderer to display, and now I'd like to add an animation effect when the user filters their results.

I know that you can use the itemsChangeEffect to create an animation effect when the user drags and moves result itmes.

So I'd like to know if there's a way to create a similar effect triggered by the filtering on the comboboxes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Ended up with a bit a word around.

By using two states I was able to achieve the look I wanted. Just used some simple if statements and state changes with Transitions.

```
            if (this.currentState == 's1'){
                this.currentState = 's2';
            } else if (this.currentState == 's2'){
                this.currentState = 's1';
            }
            acData.refresh();
```